# UiwebView not resizable to page

Tags: uiwebview

my page (google for example) isn't adjust to my web view. Why?
[image]

The Same code in TestAViewController works.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: @AlessandroCeccon Just add it to your viewDidLoad() method before [self.webview loadRequest:urlRequest];

Comment: @AlessandroCeccon You have added it after loadRequest. Add it before as i have stated above.

Comment: Sorry, same think (see image now)